# I need a simple script for InDesign to Cut object & Paste in the centre of the same page. Please help

Tags: adobe-indesign

I would appreciate if somebody make me a very simple script for InDesign CC Windows to center the selected image on the page.

In other words I need a script that should perform only two steps.

1- Cut the selected image from the page.

3- Paste the image in the center on same page.

Thanks,

Comment: Hello @MuhammadZuhair and welcome to GDSE. We are a Q&A site and do not typically do work on request. You will probably have better luck to get an answer if you edit your post to frame it as a question (eg. What is the most simple way of...? Where can I find a script for...?)

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulillah, I created it by myself looking into different free scripts available on the web. In case, somebody need it, here is the script:

app.cut();

app.menuActions.itemByID(118788).invoke();

app.paste();